# csvsimple longtable header issue

Tags: longtable, csvsimple

I am trying to create a `longtable` from a CSV file with the help of the package `csvsimple`. I managed to get almost everything in order except for one extra line below the first header (it does not apply to successive headers on next pages).

I am guessing it comes from these two lines of code:

```
after first line=\\\midrule\endhead,
late after line=\\,
```

It seems that `csvsimple` is applying two linebreaks (`\\`) after the first line of the table which would be the header.

The thing is that if I remove the linebreak from the `after first line` argument, it seems to throw an error or do not compile at all.
And if I try to use `late after first line`, it removes the extra line but does not display the `midrule` as specified..

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
  a,b,c
  1,2,3
  4,5,6
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvloop{
  file=test.csv,
  respect all,
  separator=comma,
  no head,
  before reading={
    \begin{longtable}{lll}
    \toprule
  },
  command={\csviffirstrow
    {\textbf{\csvcoli} & \textbf{\csvcolii} & \textbf{\csvcoliii}}
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
  },
  after first line=\midrule\endhead,
  late after line=\\,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  after reading=\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. `late after first line` has to be placed after `late after line` to have an effect. Otherwise, it is overwritten by `late after line`.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
  a,b,c
  1,2,3
  4,5,6
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvloop{
  file=test.csv,
  respect all,
  separator=comma,
  no head,
  before reading={
    \begin{longtable}{lll}
    \toprule
  },
  command={\csviffirstrow
    {\textbf{\csvcoli} & \textbf{\csvcolii} & \textbf{\csvcoliii}}
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
  },
  late after line=\\,
  late after first line=\\\midrule\endhead,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  after reading=\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does indeed resolve my issue, thanks. `late after line` does not seem to actually override `late after first line` though as it still displayed the `midrule`.

Comment: @Florian In your original code you used `after first line` which is not touched by `late after line`. `late` and *not* `late` are two different proporties.

Comment: Right. I do understand what I did wrong now. Thank you very much.